# Closing Reason: Migrate to Music Fans

Tags: discussion, feature-request

After the [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) site enters the public beta phase, can we get a migrate to Music Fans Closing Reason?

There are many questions here that could fit there.

Comment: I will check, but I think "migrate to" options are limited to graduated sites

Comment: I'd wait to decide this until after it makes it to public beta when the scope is well defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a no. Tim Post's own words:

> we don't establish migration paths to a site that is still in its beta period. We don't want to send content from one site to another unless we're certain that the target site is a permanent fixture. There are exceptions to this; moderators can migrate relatively new questions to sites not in the current migration path, but this ability should be used sparingly. A question should be of much better than average quality, and all hope of it being on topic for the current site should be exhausted prior to going around the established routes.

So just flag them for a mod if they qualify, and we can move them over.

Comment: Just to clarify, does it need both sites to have graduated? We are going to graduate soon, so can we get that feature then or do we have to wait for the music fans to graduate (if it does)

Comment: It's the destination site. So yes, I expect a fair few mod messages...