# Add migration to Music Fans to the close vote options

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, migration

I see this was [proposed 5 years ago](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/closing-reason-migrate-to-music-fans).

Can we do it now? Add migration to Music Fans as an option to the close vote menu?

Comment: Oops. Nevermind. It appears that the same reason still exists. Need to get Music Fans out of beta. So if we want this to happen, the chief obstacle appears to be number of questions per day on Music Fans. So visit and ask some questions!